# Date in filename returns error runnig on Windows machine

Tags: java, windows, date, filenames

I want to create a file and use project name and date in the filename. Here is a simple Java code I used for a while on my Unix machine.

```
    String fileName = projectName + "," + (date.toString());
    PrintStream pr = new PrintStream(new File(fileName));
```

Recently, I tried to run my code on a Windows machine and I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Test,Thu Sep 03 12:28:33 EDT 2015 (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

When I remove the date from the filename, everything works perfect. Any suggestion what is the problem of date in filename and how I can fix it?

Comment: Print out the file name once you've concatenated the date. Is there a file with that String as its name?

Comment: Probably the file name contains character that are not allowed on Windows like `:`.

Comment: date likely contains / or : or some other illegal character http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names

Comment: Use a date format like `yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss` to avoid file naming problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name `Test,Thu Sep 03 12:28:33 EDT 2015` is invalid on Windows because it contains a `:`. `:` is reserved for delimiting the end of a drive letter (e.g., `c:`). You can't have colons in filenames on Windows.

Comment: That's half the answer ("what is the problem"). The other half is "how I can fix it". :-)

Comment: @Andreas: I should have thought that was obvious: Don't put `:` in your filename. *How* you do that is an incredibly broad topic.

Comment: Sure, but a suggestion, like  RealSkeptic's comment to the question, would make your answer *complete*.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few limitations for characters which are allowed for filenames in windows.

See [the official Windows file naming limitations at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)

I would suggest specifying a format when calling `date.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `date.toString()` which can be different depending on the OS and it may turns out in invalid characters for file name. Try to use `d.getTime()` so your code will be:

```
String fileName = projectName + "-" + date.getTime();
```

`getTime()` Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.

And also change the comma. As it can be problematic as well.

Comment: You can still use date.toString(), but specify an appropriate format string.

Comment: @ManuelZametter This suggestion avoids the OP the need to know which characters are invalid in the OS, therefore no need for a format which may have a format with dashs or something valid. The idea here is to not spend useless lines of code. K.I.S.S. always.